# PHPUnit mock/stub functionality within class

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit, stub

I need some advice on how I can proceed with this issue.

Using PHP
An example would be:

```
class BuilderClass {
 function getClass($id, $some, $vars){
  $dbResult = new db_Class::getDbRows($id, $some, $vars);
  foreach(...)
   // Build something from the database values

  return self;
 }
}
```

So what I want to do is to create a test case where I somehow mock the db results.

I have not found any great way to do this, please point me in the right direction or similar to get this working for me.

I could change something within the builder itself for example call a class that runs the function: FunctionRunner::runStaticFunction("db_Class", "getDbRows", $args, $something_else); But at the moment I don't know if that is possible neither. Any research articles that cover this or any sites that explain this. I'd appriciate anything at the moment.

Thanks
/Marcus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the operations of retrieving data from database, and building the data.

```
class BuilderClass {
    function getClass($id, $some, $vars){
        $dbResult = new db_Class::getDbRows($id, $some, $vars);
        return doGetClass($dbResult);
    }

    function doGetClass($dbResult) {
        foreach(...)
         // Build something from the database values

        return self;   
    }
}
```

That way, you can test `doGetClass` in isolation from calling the database .

Comment: Really good idea, that way I can mock the getClass function. To do what I want instead.

Comment: This alternative gives me the option to have static function getClass. Which I failed to mention I have at the moment.

Comment: I've found this book invaluable in dealing with situations like this http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0131177052. I believe this tactic is called template redefinition.

Comment: So, is it possible to have private static function for "doGetClass" in your example there? I mean, would phpunut be able to mock a private static function?

Comment: @Oldek Using this tactic you don't need to mock getClass(). You can just instantiate an Object of BuilderClass and run the test against doGetClass by passing in a mock db_Class.

Comment: Hm, that is simple indeed. So I add complexity of one middle step and remove tons of dependability.

Comment: There is a problem with this though I relalized. Both classes has to be public.

Answer (score 1):

As often the case, inability to easily write tests for your functions is caused by a flaw in your application design. In this case the db_Class is tightly coupled to your BuilderClass.

A proper solution would be to have a Database object in your BuilderClass using dependency injection, and mocking that injection to return a static result.

```
class BuilderClass
{
    protected $oDatabase;
    public function __construct(db_Class $oDatabase) {
        $this->oDatabase = $oDataabse;
    }

    public function getClass($someVars) {
        $this->oDatabase->getDbRows($someVars);
    }
}
```

This way, the Database object is easily replaced with a stub.

Comment: Yes, in an ideal world, I would move towards this kind of solution. It's a bit chicken and egg though since the OP has working code he needs to test and ideally he would get it under test before refactoring towards this solution. A complete rebuild isn't also possible (or desirable).

Comment: I appriciate this, indeed, I should be able to make it an object rather than a static function, however the idea of just using a separate function to get the database rows.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, but since we are talking PHP, you could leverage the [magic class loader function](http://no.php.net/__autoload).

Simply put, if you want to mock the data access layer, you just create an object with the actual name of the data class, and the autoloader is never called.

Want to actually access the database? don't define the class and the autoloader will be called when something tries to access the database, which should then know what to do to load the class.

Mostly my autoloaders, when I use them, tend to look something like this;

```
function __autoload($className)
{
  if(file_exists('../includes/'.$className.'.php'))
    require_once('../includes/'.$className.'.php');
}
```

Comment: So you suggest a separate autoloaded for PHPUnit then?

Comment: That is one option, or one could simply define a mock class directly. Using an IoC pattern is a much better solution, but as this is PHP, this is a possible option - and if the system being written tests for is an old, complex system - it might be a far simpler solution.